# How can I create and save files to a directory in internal storage on windows phone with unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-phone, save, internal-storage

How can I save a file (doc or image) directly to a specified directory (will be created first time and second will check if exist put data or create and append ) in internal storage on windows phone with unity without use fileOpenPicker? This thinks I need for windows phone 10 from unity3D. Any ideea, advice is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd save data in the [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html). Most of System.IO.File is available for UWP apps so you can use that directly. If you're targeting Windows Phone 8.1 then use the alternate [UnityEngine.Windows.File](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.File.html)

If you want let the user specify a directory or use a library then you'll need to branch out from what Unity provides and use the underlying WinRT StorageFile API. See [Quickstart: Reading and writing files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325(v=win.10).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#creating_a_file).

To call WinRT classes in Unity wrap them in #if NETFX_CORE or #if WINDOWS_UWP blocks so isn't called in contexts (such as the Unity Editor) that don't have access to the Windows Runtime.

See the Unity3d [Windows Store Apps](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WindowsStore.html) docs for more info.